# How do I import single-line CSV into QuestDB?

Tags: csv, questdb

I'm trying to import a table into QuestDB via the `/imp` REST endpoint. The file contains a single row one with no column row:

```
a,10.5,True
```

I'm trying to import it with cURL:

```
curl -v -F data=@input.csv 'http://localhost:9000/imp?name=my_table'
```

but geting `not enough lines [table=my_table]` error.

How do I import a single-line CSV into QuestDB?

Answer (score 2):

To import a single-line CSV, you need to specify `forceHeader` and `delimiter` query parameters to instruct the database not to expect the column names row and not to try to automatically detect the value delimiter. E.g.:

```
curl -v -F data=@input.csv 'http://localhost:9000/imp?name=table_name&forceHeader=false&delimiter=%2C'
```

Here, `%2C` is URL-encoded comma char.